# winston logging only working in callbacks not working in catch blocks

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

I am setting up a server and want to log every errors and information in my custom files. all those errors which are caught in catch block should be store in "catch_error.log" file and all those informative messages should be stored in "console.log". so I set Winston logger to log all those stuff. a logger is an object that provides various methods. logger.log("some text") log the message on my console as well as corresponding logging file when I call it in a callback function. But when I call it from catch block it only prints on the console terminal  do not log into the corresponding logging file. why this happening?? i want to log all those messages which are in catch block.

```
const express = require(`express`);
const app = express();
const fs = require(`fs`);
const winston = require(`winston`);
const CONSOLE = new winston.transports.Console();
const ERROR = new winston.transports.File({ filename: './../../log/catch_error/catch_error.log', level: 'error' });
const INFO = new winston.transports.File({ filename: './../../log/console/console.log', level: 'info' });
const logger = winston.createLogger({
    format: winston.format.json(),
    transports: [
        CONSOLE,
        ERROR,
        INFO
    ],
    silent: false
});
let CONFIG = null
try{
    CONFIG = 
JSON.pase(fs.readFileSync('./../../../../config.json'));  //error generate pase instead of parse
}catch(err){
    logger.log({     //log on terminal but not in catch_error.log file

          level: `error`,
          message: err.message,
          stack: err.stack

    });
    //process.exit();
}
/**************************this is working*********************/
app.listen(8080, () => {

    logger.log({ //log on terminal as well as console.log file

        level: `info`,
        message: `server running at 8080`

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`process.exit()` kills the thread, so there is no time left for Winston to write to the file.

Comment: same problem after commenting ```process.exit()```