# winston is console logging but not writing or appending to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, backend, winston

Hi my problem is about Winston logging problem
when I write functions in try catch on dizipub/index.ts and
I imported function from global/globalhelper.ts
when this func name is

```
//globalhelper.ts
const compareDiffrencesArray = (input: { newArray: string[]; oldArray: string[] }) => {
  try {
    const { newArray, oldArray } = input
    const cliBar = createCliProgres({ message: 'Checking Differentses In Array', maxValue: 100, startValue: 1 })
    const tempOldArray = oldArray
    const tempNewArray = newArray
    const differentsesArray = [] as string[]
    tempNewArray.forEach((item: any, index: number) => {
      const progress = Math.ceil((index / tempNewArray.length) * 100)
      if (checkForbiddenWords(item)) {
        return
      }
      cliBar.update(progress)
      if (!tempOldArray.includes(item)) {
        differentsesArray.push(item)
      }
    })
    return differentsesArray
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(`Someting Not Well On CompareDiffrencesArray Func${err.stack}`)
    throw err
  }
}
// it is just simple compare 2 array and find differences.
```

then I am writing

```
// index.ts

const compareData = async (input?: { compiledData?: any }) => {
  try {
    let compiledData = input?.compiledData || (await fileAction.readCompiledData())

    logger.info('test Compare Data Started')
    // const xmlData = await globalHelper.sitemapExtractor({ moduleName, url: `${globalConfig.sitesUrls.dizihub}` })
    const xmlData = await path.resolve(`./src/data/sites-xmls/${moduleName}Sitemap.xml`)
    const newRawData = await globalHelper.pullRawDataFromSite({ siteMapLinkArray: [xmlData] })
    const rawData = await fileAction.readRawData()
 // part of err 
    let comparedArray = globalHelper.compareDiffrencesArray({ oldArray: rawData, newArray: newRawData })

  } catch (err) {
    await logger.error(`Error in ${moduleName} Compare Data ${err.stack ? err.stack : err}`)

    throw err
  } finally {
    logger.warn('test Compare Data Finished')
  }
}
```

when I take err like its

[log photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2tCI.png) 
writing console log colored part winston white part is nodejs exeptions but its it is not writing or appending to file.
then I search it  I find doc to winston
https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md#file-transport
this  part it say createWriteFileStream so this means it is async. than
I seach it to nodejs doc so I find this
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fscreatewritestreampath-options

and this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57562515/20358783

Then I write like this winston file

```
    new winston.transports.File({
        options: { autoClose: false, flags: 'as+' },
        format: winston.format.combine(
          winston.format.printf((info) => {
            console.log('girdi')
            return `${new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleDateString('tr-Tr', {
              year: 'numeric',
              month: '2-digit',
              day: '2-digit',
              hour: '2-digit',
              minute: '2-digit'
            })} ${info.level.toLocaleUpperCase()}: ${info.message}`
          })
        ),
        filename: './src/logs/globalLog.log',
        level: 'silly'
      }),
```

but its not work.

```
ProjectSeriesBackend
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┣ data
 ┃ ┃ ┣ sites-jsons
 ┃ ┃ ┗ sites-xmls
 ┃ ┣ global
 ┃ ┃ ┣ global.config.json
 ┃ ┃ ┣ global.d.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┣ globalHelper.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┗ winston.ts
 ┃ ┣ logs
 ┃ ┃ ┣ dizihub
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ dizihub-All.log
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ dizihub-Error.log
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ dizihub-Warn.log
 ┃ ┃ ┗ globalLog.log
 ┃ ┣ main
 ┃ ┗ sites
 ┃ ┃ ┣ dizihub
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ index.ts
```

```
    "tsc": "^2.0.4",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "winston": "^3.8.2"
```

I expect to know how I solve this problem and probably what the problem is.
I Search to fix this problem for probably 4+ hours more.

Thanks for answering my  sorry for my b1 English.

Comment: I tried to replicate using the code you provided, but it seems to be working here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-1wdrps?file=index.js

Comment: @vighnesh153 add me on discord pls  (FOX)#0539 so I can show you live.